# How do I create a point, buffer it, and intersect with polygon geometry?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, oracle-spatial

The sql below is intended to create a point from a know X,Y. It should then buffer the point with a known distance. Last, the sql should intersect the buffer with an underlying polygon layer and return the name field from the polygon the buffer intersects. Seems straightforward.

```
SELECT name
FROM polygons t1
WHERE sde.st_intersects (sde.st_buffer(sde.st_point(x, y), buffer), t1.SHAPE) = 1
```

When I run the sql, I get the following:

```
Error at line 3
ORA-20003: Geometry type "" is not a valid shape type.
ORA-06512: at "SDE.ST_GEOM_UTIL", line 275
ORA-06512: at "SDE.ST_POINT", line 21
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it? The X,Y I'm using are definitely in the correct area so buffering and finding an intersection should not be a problem.

I'm using st_geometry on Oracle from Arc 10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a SRID to ST_POINT.

```
SELECT name
FROM polygons t1
WHERE sde.st_intersects (sde.st_buffer(sde.st_point(x, y, SRID), buffer), t1.SHAPE) = 1
```

Comment: You'll get better performance if you place the `t1.SHAPE` parameter first in the argument list (utilizing the index on the `polygons` table)

Comment: @Vince Nice tip! A SELECT query we've been using went from 500ms to 115ms. How did you know to make that suggestion? I know geometry is indexed but how do you know switching the parameters would help?

Comment: The spatial index of the first parameter is used.  If the first parameter is a constant, then the spatial query is a full table scan on the table of the second parameter.  The real fun comes with a spatial join of two tables; when the spatial test may be different if you change the order (e.g., ST_Contains vs. ST_Within)